# Item description from STORE to PayPal Express

Tags: expresso-store, paypal-express-checkout

I want to pass the item description from STORE to PayPal Express. At the moment in PayPal I see only the order number. All the other details are passed such as billing details, but not an item description.

I installed the CI Merchant GitHub Forkbut its still the same? I made sure I replaced the current file with: system/expressionengine/third_party/store/ci-merchant/libraries/merchant/merchant_paypal_base.php

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong or if anyone knows if its possible to pass an item or product description from STORE to PAYPAL.

I'm using the latest version of both EE and Store.

Many thanks

Graham

Comment: I tried adding item-by-item order detail to Store's PayPal Express payments (including shipping, tax, etc, all broken-out). It required modifications to a couple of files to get working ... but in the end it still threw an error after payment, during the verification callback. Eventually gave up.

Comment: We're trying to do the same thing here but keep getting 0. We want to pass through the item names that are in the cart. ANyone that can help?

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to modify `merchant_paypal_express.php` if you want to include transaction details with the payment request.

On or around line 84 you'll see the `_build_authorize_or_purchase` method where the details are passed on to Paypal. You'll need to edit this to include the description with the [OrderDescription](http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_APIReference/expresscheckout.html).

Comment: Hi Ian, Many thanks for your reply. I gave it a go, but nothing worked out, just got errors. Do you have an example of the updated code?

Comment: Hi Graham. What are the errors you're getting back from Paypal?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. The errors were my fault as I was not sure about what I needed to edit. However I am going to do a bit more research before I ask for help and if successful I will post the code back here.

Comment: Hi Ian, I added this line: $request[$prefix.'DESC'] = $this->param('OrderDescription'); I do not get an error, but in PayPal the Description now has the value of '0'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latest store update does exactly this

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html

Answer (score -1):

**Just Change your paypal url to **

"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=$your_token&useraction=commit"